# Addons in Docker Odoo 13.0 not recognized

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-13

I try to use latest (13.0) Docker image for local development and I'm using docker-compose.yml from docker documentation for spinning up containers:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:13.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons/my_module:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

My odoo.conf:

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
```

My file structure:

```
├── addons
│   └── my_module
│       ├──controllers
│       ├──demo
│       ├──models
│       ├──security
│       ├──views
│       ├──__init__.py
│       └──__manifest__.py
├── config
│   └── odoo.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── README.md
```

my_module is [default module strucure](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/_downloads/my_module.zip) from odoo website (with uncommented code) so I'm assuming it has no errors.

When I start the containers with command `docker-compose up -d` it starts the database and odoo without any errors (in docker and in browser console) but my_module is not visible inside application. I turned on developer mode and Updated Apps list inside App tab as suggested in other issues on github and SO but my_module is still not visible. Additionally if I login to container with `docker exec -u root -it odoo /bin/bash` I can cd to /mnt/extra-addons and I can see the contents of my_module mounted to container so it seems as Odoo does not recognize it?

I scanned the interned and found many similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try to look into Odoo's log and look out for the used addons path. If your path isn't used, Odoo's possibly not using your config file.

Comment: you need to make sure of what @CZoellner said. also you could override the run command of docker as following:
`docker-compose run --rm -p 8869:8069 /usr/bin/odoo --config=/etc/odoo`

Comment: whats inside your `__manifest__.py`

Comment: @CZoellner were exactly are logs located? I can't see any file related to odoo inside /var/log/ or /var/log/odoo

Comment: @Paxmees `__manifest__.py` is generic as it is in this [zip](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/_downloads/my_module.zip)

Comment: @metodribic log should be seen with `docker-compose logs <service_name>`

Comment: @CZoellner I checked the logs and I can verify that config is used and addon path includes /mnt/extra-addons. Extract from logs: 

`INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf 
INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/var/lib/odoo/addons/13.0', '/mnt/extra-addons'] `

Comment: Hm that looks good. What about the access rights on this directory? Does the odoo starting user have atleast rights to read the directory/files?

Comment: Just gave addons/my_module drwxrwxrwx rights and there is no difference.

Comment: @kerbrose with your command I'm getting `ERROR: No such service: /usr/bin/odoo`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @metodribic well, the name of the service is missing
`docker-compose run --rm -p 8869:8069 [SERVICE NAME PROBABLY ODOO] /usr/bin/odoo --config=/etc/odoo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I ended up with this `docker-compose.yml` which does load custom addons to my Docker:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: always
  odoo:
    image: odoo:13
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    tty: true
    command: -- --dev=reload
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    restart: always
```

`odoo.conf`:

```yaml
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
logfile = /etc/odoo/odoo-server.log
```

Comment: I am using --dev all on development environments. Read your docker-compose document and change ``version: '2'`` line to a newer one. its at least 3 now, it affects behavior. https://docs.docker.com/compose/, I don't know what's changed it for you but odoo defiantly adds some addons paths for you. That ``-- `` parameter looks strange.  I think you managed to call full rebuild and that why it's working now ??